# Looking for names for some Classes

Tags: names

I am writing some program for publishing and I would like to ask you for a help.

I have two classes and I would like to give them preferably single word names:

- One is for Publication / Magazine (name that denotes whole brand - every number ever printed)
- Other is for a single number of some Magazine

So I have a question for native English speakers: What are most natural distinct English names for those two (all that I have in my head is Magazine for both cases)?

Comment: A formal (librarian's) word for a magazine is _journal_ or _periodical_. _Number_ is fine for a single edition, or you could use _issue_.

Comment: You can check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodical_literature for information on how the publishing industry talks about these things.

Comment: [ +1 ] One is a [A] "Publication_Series / Magazine_Series / Periodical_Series" & the other is a [B] "Publication_Issue / Magazine_Issue / Periodical_Issue" , where the [A] object contains a collection of [B] objects. Highlighting "Series" versus "Issue" with a lot of variations.

Comment: Thanks for yours suggestions

Answer (score 1):

When magazines are published, they are usually given some designation that serves as their unique code or number. It might be a number, or it could be a date. For example:

> Volume 10. No. 2

> Issue 12

> March 1999

If you want to call the first class "Magazine" you could call the second class "Volume" or "Issue" or "MonthYear" -- something that corresponds to the way they are "numbered."

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion